# Injectivity of pushforward of rational Chow groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, chow-groups, projective-varieties

I'd like to know whether there is a known counter-example to the following statement. Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a finite field. Let $Z$ be a codimension $2$ smooth subvariety which is the intersection of two hypersurface sections in $X$. Is the pushforward $CH_i(Z)\otimes \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow CH_i(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ injective?

Comment: This is not true for surfaces $S \subseteq \mathbf P^3$ (embed them linearly in $\mathbf P^4$ if you insist on codimension $2$ complete intersections). The Picard rank can be more than $1$.

Comment: Not true either for a curve in $\Bbb{P}^3$, for the same reason.

Comment: @abx over finite fields and when tensored with $\mathbf Q$, it should be injective for curves, as $\operatorname{Pic}^0(C)$ is torsion and smooth projective curves have Picard rank $1$.

Comment: @R. van Dobben de Bruyn: Oops, you are right of course. I forgot the $\otimes \mathbb{Q}$.